# circular/round loop based on ID (start with specific ID add the rest of the ID, break when specific ID reached)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

Consider I have array of IDs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Let's say I can fetch an array starting with an ID of specific number, let's say 5.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM farmlist WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id")
```

it should give me array of form:

```
5
6
7
8
```

**Question:** Is there a way after reaching the last ID, it would add to array the IDs from the smallest until the ID of where we start, so that we have:

```
5
6
7
8
1 <~ Add
2 <~ Add
3 <~ Add
4 <~ Add
```

Comment: so how many such ids you may have in the table ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I only start with one specific ID. The number of IDs/entries in my database varies... did I answer your question sir?

Comment: in a single query this could be done where you select some data order by with condition and rest with other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM farmlist WHERE id > 4  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM farmlist WHERE id <= 4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$arr = array(5,6,7,8);
sort($ids);
sort($arr);
$min = $arr[0];
foreach($ids as $id){
   if($id>=$min) break;
   $arr[]=$i;
}
//array will now be (5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4)
```

That what you wanted?

Comment: Sir, we cannot simply increment +1, since we can have non uniform incrementing IDs: **1,2,4,7,8**

Answer (score 1):

With mysql this could be done as

```
mysql> create table test (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0



mysql> select * from test order by case when id >=5 then 0 else 1 end , id  ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

The above query could be even expanded in a range, lets say I want data from 5 till 7 on the top and rest all after that and this could be done as

```
mysql> select * from test order by case when id >=5 and id<8 then 0 else 1 end , id  ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id from farmlist
order by 
(select if( id > 4, id - 4, id + (select max(id) + 1 from farmlist)))
```

Answer (score 1):

pseudo-code:

```
res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM farmlist WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id");
res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM farmlist WHERE id <= 4 ORDER BY id");
array_merge(res1, res2);
```

and the final res would be in `res1`

Comment: Great man. I know this is supposed to work, but the other answers here suggest a single mysql_query command.

Comment: since you tagged `php` in your question, I thought you need to figure out how to do it in `php`